# function SetWindowText() doesnt work

Tags: windows, winapi, opengl

I'm trying to set infos on the title bar with this function from my simple application:

```
void WindowGL::SetInfoTitleBar(HWND hwnd)
{
  char bufor[256];
  GetWindowText(hwnd, bufor, 256);
  const GLubyte* ver = glGetString(GL_VERSION);
  strcat_s(bufor, " | OpenGL ");
  strcat_s(bufor, (char*)ver);
  const GLubyte* ven = glGetString(GL_VENDOR);
  strcat_s(bufor, " | ");
  strcat_s(bufor, (char*)ven);
  const GLubyte* ren = glGetString(GL_RENDERER);
  strcat_s(bufor, " | ");
  strcat_s(bufor, (char*)ren);

  if (SetWindowText(hwnd,  bufor ) == false){
      MessageBox(NULL, bufor, bufor, MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
  }

}
```

When debugging, the effect is i got message box containing two the same texts (one on title bar); but when clicking OK button, i got white app window rendered correctly but on title bar is a window name only from WNDCLASSEX class.

Im using VS 2013 Express, win 7 64 bit. This code is from the book, i'm learning from. The author also was using VS 2013 (but not express) and win 7 (probably 32 bit version). Character set is Multi-Byte. Pls any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Don't test `== false`. Test logic with `if (b)` or `if (!b)`. Then, read the docs. When `SetWindowText` fails, the docs tell you to call `GetLastError`. If I had to guess, I'd guess that `hwnd` is not what you expect it to be. You also fail to check the return value of `GetWindowText` for errors. Please please please check for errors.

Comment: Solved! You have right - the function was called with bad named hwnd argument. Very very very thank You!

Comment: Don't vote guys badly, i was fighting two days with this function, casting, combination, converting, nothing worked until this guy show me what i was doing bad. I'm not as pro as you.

Comment: There's no length guarantee for returned strings in GL. Probably 99.9% of the time 256 characters is enough (certainly more characters than any window title deserves), but just to be safe, `strncat` exists. Seems silly, I know, but some vendors have absurdly long strings for renderer / version.